# Roles in FlowRouter is working flappy

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, flow-router

i'm trying to redirect a user to 403 page when not authorized. I added roles 'admin', 'default-group' to CM9Cwq7HXD6yHjKRp and it's working like a charm on template level. But not working as expected on router.

My route groups are separated into 2 main group

```
// Public routes
var publicFlowRouter; 
publicFlowRouter  = FlowRouter.group({});

// Private routes
var privateFlowRouter;
privateFlowRouter = FlowRouter.group({
  triggersEnter: [
    function() {

    var route;

    if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId())) {

      route = FlowRouter.current();

      if (route.route.name !== 'home') {
        Session.set('redirectAfterLogin', route.path);
      }

      return FlowRouter.go('home');
    }
  }
  ]
});
```

There isn't any problem for these routes but the problem starts with adminPrivateFlowRouter;

```
// Private routes extended for admin
var adminPrivateFlowRouter;
adminPrivateFlowRouter = privateFlowRouter.group({
  triggersEnter: [ 
    function() {
      // If user is not authenticated redirect to homepage
      console.log(Meteor.userId());
      console.log(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin', 'default-group'));
      if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin', 'default-group')) {
        console.log('Authenticated user');       
      } else {
        console.log('403 Access Denied');
        //return FlowRouter.go('home');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

is not working solid. When i refresh the samepage console says sometimes
CM9Cwq7HXD6yHjKRp
false
403 Access Denied

CM9Cwq7HXD6yHjKRp
true
Authenticated user

I couldn't find where the problem is, thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, only that it's working properly on localhost but not on the server. And I get consistent results, my call to `userIsInRole` is always false, which is not ok. Also asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751753/how-to-make-flowrouter-wait-for-users-collection-on-the-client

Answer (score 0):

See [How to make FlowRouter wait for users collection on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751753/how-to-make-flowrouter-wait-for-users-collection-on-the-client/37814296#37814296)

You can solve your problem manually initializing FlowRouter with `FlowRouter.wait()` and `FlowRouter.initialize()` when `Roles` subscription is ready.