# How to make FlowRouter wait for users collection on the client

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I'm writing a section of my app which requires the user to have the 'operator' role.
I'm checking for this in FlowRouter's `triggersEnter` function. I want that the user which doesn't have the operator role to be shown a restricted access page.

I use FlowRouter, Roles and brettle:accounts-deluxe which auto logs in as guest every visitor.

Here is my code, `routes.js`:

```
FlowRouter.route('/switchboard', {
  name: 'switchboard',
  triggersEnter: [function (context, redirect, stop) {
    if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['operator'])) {
      BlazeLayout.render('main', {
        content: 'restrictedAccess'
      });           
      stop();
    }
  }],
  action: function () {
    BlazeLayout.render('main', {
        content: 'switchboard'
    });
  }
});
```

Everything works as expected on localhost, but when the app is deployed using `mup`, on a server, at the time `triggersEnter` is ran, `Meteor.user()` is `undefined` (Meteor.userId() returns ok), and the result of `Roles.userIsInRole` call is `false`, although looking in the database it's clear the user has the operator role.

I think the users subscription is not available at the time triggersEnter is ran meaning that the users collection is not published on the client. I have this feeling because if i access the route by clicking on a link the userIsInRole result is ok, but if I refresh the page I get the problem described.
I would like to know why is this happening only on the server and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that FlowRouter `triggersEnter` is not blocking templates from rendering and it makes checking roles before `Roles` collections are subscribed. Solution is to use `FlowRouter.wait()` on app init and then make the global subscription for `Roles` (you need it global - not tied to template level) collection and call `FlowRouter.initialize()` when its ready.

That way FlowRouter will wait for your collection and will be initialized after it's ready to check.

***Update***

On localhost there is much less latency between local db and app. When your app is deployed is takes more time for client to fetch data from database. In result on localhost your collection is ready when FlowRouter initializes and on deployed app it isn't.

Comment: Yep, but this would slow down the page load.

Comment: I've removed the accepted answer marker because I didn't get any answer on the question 'why is it happening only on the server?'

Comment: That's more like it. I was expecting that answer. I wanted to have it in the accepted answer for it to look more complete.

Comment: Can you put a code sample? I'm using `Roles` with `FlowRouter` and it doesn't work for me when you type the url on the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Template.subscriptionsReady` flag

```
<template name="blogPost">
  <a href="/">Back</a>
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#with post}}
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <p>{{content}}</p>
    {{/with}}
  {{else}}
      <p>Loading...</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

check full doc here:
https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-blaze
to see how to handle individual subscriptions

Comment: This isn't the solution I'm looking for, I know I can restrict the access at the template level. Or is this the only way I can accomplish access restriction on a page based on user roles?
And also, why is this issue occurring only on the server?